# Getting an error while running this T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting errors when I write this code. How can I fix it?
It says the error is on 'in'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spPracticum
    (@MaxCountry As VARCHAR,
     @MinCountry As VARCHAR)
AS
    SELECT 
        [Country], [Year], [Subscribers], c.[name]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[cell phone subscribers] AS s
    JOIN
        [dbo].[countries] AS c ON s.[Country] = c.[country-code]
    WHERE 
        @MinCountry <= Country 
        AND @MaxCountry >= Country IN (SELECT MAX(Subscribers) 
                                       FROM [dbo].[cell phone subscribers] )
    ORDER BY
        Year
```

Comment: you might be trying this `@MaxCountry >= Country  and country in (Select max query)`

Comment: Two errors I can see.  First, no parentheses in your create statement (use those in functions not procs)  Second, your where clause.  @ min <= country and @ max >= Country... from here your "IN(select...) does not make sense.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your case, *both* parameters are defaulting to a length of ***1*** character - which is typically *not* what you want ....

Comment: I seriously doubt that you're trying to check that `Country` is related to the maximum value of `Subscribers` - so what we're you even *trying* to do in that `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The previous commentators described the problems well enough. In future, if you get an error, *at least* provide the error message!

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you're getting right now (which I assume is `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.` is due to the second part of your `WHERE` clause:

```
 AND @MaxCountry >= Country IN (SELECT MAX(Subscribers)                                       
                                FROM [dbo].[cell phone subscribers] )
```

This is an invalid statement - you can use `AND @MaxCountry >= Country` to only return records where the `s.[Country]` value is less than or equal to the provided value for the `@MaxCountry` parameter, but you cannot then add an `IN` statement to the end of this, as it makes no sense and SQL doesn't understand what you're trying to do.

It's not entirely clear to me what you **are** trying to do, so I can't provide much further guidance than that - if you can clarify your question to give us some idea of expected and current output based on a given input, then we might be able to help further.

Try reading the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), perhaps along with [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).